# Opens single URLs to multiple browsers

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a little problem. How to enter a single link / url example: `www.google.com` with many different browsers? So I just include a link which will open those links in many browsers
Please help with any programming and if you can use CMD / batch program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save this as a bath file. i.e `myscript.cmd` file. When you double click the file it will prompt for a url, enter it and it will open in 3 browsers. If you have these browsers that is.

```
@echo off
Set /p "var=enter the URL: "
Start "" chrome "%var%"
Start "" iexplore "%var%"
Start "" firefox "%var%"
```

You could also make the file return to the start so you can keep it open and enter new URL's.

```
@echo off
:start
Cls
Set /p "var=enter the URL: "
Start "" chrome "%var%"
Start "" iexplore "%var%"
Start "" firefox "%var%"
Goto :start
```

You could even do it in a `for` loop.

```
@echo off
Set "browsers=iexplore chrome firefox"
Cls
Set /p "var=enter the URL: "
Set "browsers=iexplore chrome firefox"
For %%i in (%browsers%) do start "" %%i "%var%"
```